# New to Firebase, have a few questions about custom user auth and storing data on Android.

Tags: firebase

I'm implementing Firebase in an Android app and have a few questions.

1) I'll be using custom auth and the docs say to perform the token generation on a "Secure Server", because my secret will exposed. Does this mean it's not safe to do within my login activity class, or is this secure?

2) I'll be sending several required values to my database upon registration (username, password, etc). Will this just be done like this...

```
var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(
    {uid: "custom:1", username: "string", password: "string"});
```

? If so, how do I securely store the passwords?

3) I'll be saving images to my database, some of which will be quite large (iPhone 6 and Galaxy s6 take some ridiculous pictures). Will I be fine to just store the byte[], along with other info about the image (uploader, data, etc)? Or is there a better way to do it?

Sorry for the long post, just want to make sure I know what I'm doing before diving in :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I'll be using custom auth and the docs say to perform the token
>   generation on a "Secure Server", because my secret will exposed. Does
>   this mean it's not safe to do within my login activity class, or is
>   this secure?

This means it cannot be stored in the client, period. Storing the secret anywhere in the Android application is insecure. Token generation should only take place on a server.

> If so, how do I securely store the passwords?

If you're just looking for password-based authentication, try Firebase's [built-in password authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html) which will remove the need to generate tokens in your client app.

> Will I be fine to just store the byte[], along with other info about
>   the image (uploader, data, etc)? Or is there a better way to do it?

Firebase currently only allows storage of strings, booleans, and numbers, so any binary data will need to be Base64-encoded before storing. Stay tuned though, more options are coming!

**Update (20160519)**: *Firebase just released a new feature called [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/). This allows you to upload images and other non-JSON data to a dedicated storage service. We highly recommend that you use this for storing images, instead of storing them as base64 encoded data in the JSON database.*